# Problem using hash map to find the first unique element in a string in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

```
int firstUniqChar(std::string s) {
    //Using maps to find the first unique character of the string
    int string_len;
    int pos;
    std::unordered_map<char, int> m{};
    string_len = s.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < string_len; i++) {
        //if the char in string is not present in map, then add to the map with a 
        //frequency of 1.
        if(m.find(s[i]) == m.end()) {
            m.insert(std::make_pair(s[i], 1));
        } else {
            m[s[i]]++;            
        }
    }     
    
    for(std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        if (it->second == 1) {
           int index = std::distance(m.begin(), it);                
            return index;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I am trying to find the first unique element in a string using maps in c++. Though i am able to count the frequency of elements, the code does not return the first unique element. Something to do with the ordering in maps. how do I get the first unique element.

Adding another code with array which does not cover all cases

```
int main() {
std::string s = "aadadaad";
int len = s.length();

if (len == 1) {
    return 0;
}

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    bool found = true;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
        if (s[i] == s[j]) {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ((i != len - 1) && (found == true)) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
        return i;
    }
}

std::cout << "-1" << std::endl;
return -1;
```

}

Comment: What does the code return ?

Comment: "First" has no real meaning for an **unordered** container. The order of the elements is unspecified and is not meaningful other than to the container's implementation. If you are trying to find the first element in terms of insertion order, then you cannot use an associative container. Associative container ordering is arranged to speed up searches and loses all information about insertion order.

Comment: @DeepakPatankar the code returns the first unique element in a string

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Hash maps are the only way i can count the frequency of the duplicate elements efficiently. I have seen the java and python implementation.  The same does not seem to work for me in C++

Comment: @AnjanaRajam If a Java or Python hash container reports on the insertion order of its elements, then it is hiding additional data structures internally. A hash map cannot track insertion order. The insertion order needs to be tracked in a separate container, or possibly embedded with each element at the cost of very slow iteration.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So after getting a map with elements and frequencies, is there a way I can set it in the order like that of the original string?

Comment: @AnjanaRajam Not directly. But you can iterate over the input string again, and use the map you generated to associate frequency with insertion order. For example, instead of looking for the first element with `second == 1` you would look through the input string for the first character whose associated value is 1 in the map. Edit : This is what eerorika meant in their answer with *"What you should do instead is once you have calculated the frequencies, iterate the string again and return the first character with frequency of 1."*.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Thank you so much. I finally understood. thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are returning is the first element of an unordered map. That element being first has nothing to do what is the first unique element of the string.

What you should do instead is once you have calculated the frequencies, iterate the string again and return the first character with frequency of 1.

---

P.S. If you can assume a 8 bit byte - which may be a reasonable assumption - then there are only 256 different values. Instead of a hashmap, a likely more efficient solution is to use an array of 256 elements. Note that you need to convert to unsigned char to use a character as an index.

Comment: That is what I am doing. I am returning the first character with frequency 1. But that first character does not appear as first character, it is randomly placed elsewhere. This is where its going wrong

Comment: @AnjanaRajam `That is what I am doing. I am returning the first character with frequency 1. ` You are returning first character of unordered map, yes. As far as I understand, that is not what your function is supposed to return. Aren't you supposed to return the first unique character of the string?

Comment: Like hashmap, array does not cover all corner cases. I did try it out.

Comment: @AnjanaRajam Which corner do you think an array doesn't cover?

Comment: I am returning the first character with frequency 1, not the first character. it->second == 1 is nothing but the frequency. But as I said first character with frequency 1 is randomly placed elsewhere, due to  which results are incorrect

Comment: @AnjanaRajam You are missing the point. You are returning first character (yes, with frequency 1, but that is not the point) **of the unordered map**. According to description of what you were supposed to do, that is not what you described. You were supposed to return the first unique character of the string.

Comment: @AnjanaRajam I'm not sure if you are describing a problem with the `unordered_map` solution or with the proposed array based solution. But the same problem applies to both solutions. You'll need to iterate some part of the string again.

Comment: @eerorika I have placed the array based code. The example string does not work with that code. **And the first unique character of the string is the nothing but the first character with frequency 1**. And I am not able to get the right result with maps.

Comment: @AnjanaRajam That is because you are trying to return the first unique character of the map, when you are supposed to return first unique character of the string. See my answer for how to do that. I'll repeat it here: Iterate the string; not the map.

Comment: @eerorika Okay. I got it now. Thank you so much. Should have thought a bit more. Thanks a lot :-)